# htaccess & Symfony, one single route leads to 404, but works with app_dev.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have an admin area where I login as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html).
This form works in dev enviroment, but when I switch to production the /admin route returns a 404.

The Controller (404 when not using app_dev.php):

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin", name="mainPage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', array());
}
```

My .htaccess in /web (removed comments for readability)

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And finally, my 000-default.conf

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web

<Directory /var/www/html/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Where is the error? The `/admin/login` route shows the login form. After the login I am moved to `admin/` (with 404), but when I enter another address manually that is protected it works (e.g. `admin/setup/prices`) as I am actually logged in.

Changing the route from `/admin` to `/admin/start` for example does not change anything.

If you need the security.yml:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:

encoders:
  Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
  AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        provider: our_db_provider

        form_login:
            login_path: login_route
            check_path: login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            use_referer: true
        logout:
            path:   logout_route
            target: mainPage
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
```

UPDATE
I see now that `/admin` is actually called but get 301 to `/admin/`

So I think the issue is with this line from the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Changing the route in the controller to `/admin/` does not help though.

Comment: Do you clear all caches?

Answer (score 0):

In prod env', maybe you can share us your production logs about the error?

Else, did you tried to make a specific fire rules?

```
firewalls:
    login_firewall:
        pattern:   ^/login$
        anonymous: ~
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login: ~
```